# Doing a redirection if timeout in Symfony 2.8

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

My symfony project is in a folder named /sf and when a user timeout he goes to /sf/login, how can i do to make the redirection to / when the user timeout ?

I've looked for this over the FOS git, but i've found nothing interesting.

Comment: You mean session timeout?

Comment: @hizbul25 yes i do.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't matter if you are using FOS or not, you can do it by adding the "remember_me" option in the firewalls config (locates in the security.yml). [It's a native SF2 feature](http://symfony.com/doc/current/security/remember_me.html).

It's can be like this:

```
firewalls:
    main:
        pattern: ^/
        form_login:
            provider: fos_userbundle
            csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager
            success_handler: user.login.after
        logout:       true
        anonymous:    true
        remember_me:
            secret:   '%secret%'
            lifetime: 604800 # 1 week in seconds
            path:     /
```

Comment: i'm actualy in autologon i think the problem is here.